# UIScrollView decrease bottom height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to decrease the bottom height of UIScrollView. For more details click on this link 
[scrollview image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83vdjukqg2nzyxl/Screenshot%202014.png?dl=0)

in that image red color box is extra space. dashly image is another view. My scroller runs between Apple and Dashly view. When i move that scroller content size bottom shows more height.
I done this through storyboard. Added constraints also.

```
//_scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
_scrollViewOutlet.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -7, 0);
```

i tried the above two lines but it is not worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
_scrollViewOutlet.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -100, 0);
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: thats the hacky way, you should be setting the contentSize to the actual height of the content, then you wont get that white space.

Comment: i am unable to decrease the content height

Comment: For a test, set the content height to being _scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 100);
Is the content cut off? it should be

Comment: Strange, it should set the content size. Without having the project infront of me, its hard to tell. Maybe an autolayout issue? Anyway, i guess for now you could adjust the insets, but be aware of any unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that the scrollview thinks it has a larger content size than it does. 
You need to set the content size of the scrollview, calculate this correctly and set it, then it will work fine.
Dont hack it, by adjusting the insets.

Comment: how should i decrease that height through coding?

Comment: Yes, so get the height of all the content views and add them together, OR if your content is always static, you could just manually work out the height and set it.

Comment: _scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
Where 650 is the height of your content, which you calculate by getting the height of the views